# How `TextControlPlaceholderForeground` resource doesn't appy to TextBox

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp-xaml

I got started learning Universal Windows Apps. For my demo application, I am trying to change the placeholder foreground of a `TextBox` control. To set its color, I set a resource key called `TextControlPlaceholderForeground` (as per [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox?view=winrt-22000#control-style-and-template)) on the same XAML page definition that contains the control. However, the placeholder color of `TextBox` is not set. It looks as if no placeholder text is set when the control is not in a focused state. When it receives focus, the placeholder becomes visible, but still not the color that is set to it. Here is my XAML:

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="MyApp.AuthenticationPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyApp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Page.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlPlaceholderForeground" Color="Green" />
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Border
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            Margin="0,0,0,10"
            Background="White"
            Padding="10"
            CornerRadius="10"
            Width="300"
        >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <!-- The placeholder of the TextBox below doesn't become green -->
                <TextBox x:Name="emailInput" PlaceholderText="Email" Margin="0,0,0,10" />
                
                <!-- However, the placeholder of this PasswordBox becomes green -->
                <PasswordBox x:Name="passwordInput" PlaceholderText="Password" Margin="0,0,0,10" />

                <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Content="LOG IN" Click="onLoginSubmit" Style="{StaticResource AccentButtonStyle}"/>
                <HyperlinkButton FontSize="11" Foreground="Black" Content="Forgot your password?" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBlock Text="Don't have an account yet?" Foreground="Black" FontSize="11" Padding="0,0,5,0"/>
                    <HyperlinkButton Padding="0" FontWeight="Normal" >
                        <TextBlock Text="Create new account" Foreground="Black" TextDecorations="Underline" FontSize="11"/>
                    </HyperlinkButton>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

An observation: When I try to set `TextBox`'s placeholder text color via `Style` tags, it works.

```xml
<Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="PlaceholderForeground" Value="Green" />
</Style>
```

I didn't understand what happens here. I know I am missing something very small but couldn't see it.

Comment: Any updates about this?

Answer (score 1):

First, let me explain why the second approach works. There is a little bit of difference between the **PasswordBox** and the **TextBox** about how they defined the Placeholder Text color. Both of the **PasswordBox** and the **TextBox** has a `PlaceholderTextContentPresenter` element in their styles which is a `TextBlock`. But they have different value for the Foreground property when using this `TextBlock`.

**TextBox:**

```
<TextBlock x:Name="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Foreground="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForeground}}"
```

**PasswordBox**

```
 <TextBlock x:Name="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Foreground="{ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForeground}"
```

You could see that the **PasswordBox** is directly using the `TextControlPlaceholderForeground` that you defined as the color but the **TextBox** is using a binding and the binding source is the `PlaceholderForeground` property. So when you set this property, the **TextBox** will show the color as you want.

So back to the first question, if you want to change the foreground of the Placeholder Text, you will need to create a default style of the **TextBox** and change the binding of the Foreground of the `PlaceholderTextContentPresenter` element to use the `TextControlPlaceholderForeground`directly like what the **PasswordBox ** did.